# Relative path for data file in NodeJS module

Tags: node.js, typescript, path, node-modules

I created a NodeJS module, written in typescript (though it shouldn't change anything).

Here's how it's organized:

```
.
├── data/
│   └── MY_DATA_FILES.json
│
├── src/
│   ├── data/
│   │   └── data.ts
│   │
│   └── OTHER_TYPESCRIPT_FILES.ts
│
├── dist/
│   ├── data/
│   │   └── data.js
│   │
│   └── OTHER_JAVASCRIPT_FILES.ts
│
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json
```

My goal is to read the data files from the `data.ts` file. When my current working directory in on the root of the module it's not a problem (then it would be `./data/...`) but when I use this  as a module, and it's placed in the `nodes_modules/` directory, I'm not sure how to handle the situation.

I'm currently reading the files as follow:

```js
import fs from 'fs';
const basePath = './data';
const filesPath = 'subdirectory/my_data.json';

export function getData(): any {
    const fileFullPath  = basePath + '/' + filesPath;
    const contents = fs.readFileSync(fileFullPath);

    // [...]
}
```

But here, my `basePath` is dependent on my working directory. I could set it as `./node_modules/my_module/data`, but I know that's not the right approach..

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would typically build a path for each location that is relative to the directory where your code is located and access the desired location in a relative way from that.  The location of your code will be passed to the code's module as `__dirname`.  You can then combine that relative path with `__dirname` to build a full path to the target location without making any assumptions about where or how the module is installed.

So, assuming your code is in the `src` directory, that would be where `__dirname` points to.  To, get access to the `data` directory below the `src` directory, you would use:

```
let srcDataDir = path.join(__dirname, "data");
```

To get access to the `dist/data` directory, you would use:

```
let distDataDir = path.join(__dirname, '../dist/data');
```

To get access to the higher level data directory where `MY_DATA_FILES.json` is, you would use:

```
let topDataDir = path.join(__dirname, '../data');
```

As, you can see, the key is to build everything relative from the location you do know which is `__dirname` passed to the code as the location of the code's own directory.

In Javascript's modules, you don't ever want to make any assumptions about the current working directory because that can literally be anything.  That's controlled by the top level program itself and how the program was started and is not anything the module itself can rely on or make assumptions about.  But `__dirname` will always be the full path to the directory where your module's code is running from.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, I didn't know about `__dirname`. Thanks a bunch!